# Does Google consider a website that publishes data reports (same words, different numbers) as duplicate content?

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, duplicate-content

I am working on a website that generate reports from a template. This template will be using the exact same keywords but different numbers to generate webpages that contains reports.
The generated reports (web pages) will have completely different numbers but will be same keyword structure.
The template is about 1400 words checked for plagiarism and has 100% unique content and it will use the same keywords to generate reports with different numbers.

What are the possible challenges that could happen from this approach?

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that Google may consider them duplicate or near duplicate and canonicalise (merge) them to one of the duplicates. This could mean that one will rank and the others will be considered as the same.

The best way to find out is to check them in the Google Search Console to see if their canonical values are to themselves or another one in the set.

Note that there is no duplicate penalty, just a filter and merging.

Comment: My worry is that Google does not index the pages from the uploaded sitemap because they will be hundreds of pages.

Comment: The sitemap will not include a page as indexed if it is not chosen as its own canonical. That can be another clue if Google is canonicalising out pages as duplicates.